# How to run django runserver over TLS 1.2

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ssl, tls1.2

I'm testing Stripe orders on my local Mac OS X machine. I am implementing this code:

```
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET

        order = stripe.Order.create(
          currency = 'usd',
          email = 'j@awesomecom',
          items = [
                    {
                      "type":'sku',
                      "parent":'sku_88F260aQ',
                      "quantity": 1,
                    }
                  ],
          shipping = {
            "name":'Jenny Rosen',
            "address":{
              "line1":'1234 Main Street',
              "city":'Anytown',
              "country":'US',
              "postal_code":'123456'
            }
          },
        )
```

I receive an error:

> Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please
>   initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.

I am using django 1.10 and python version 2.7.10

How can I force the use of TLS 1.2?  Would I do this on the python or django side?

Comment: Can you show/tell how are you connecting with Stripe API in your application/project? Django's runserver doesn't support HTTPS but your problem suggests that you are using old TLS mechanism.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadManzoor  I added the code.  It has no reference to TLS though.

Comment: It means that you are using another application in your project for interacting with Stripe, correct? Are you using the latest version of that application/library?

Answer (score 6):

I solved installing this libraries:

```
pip install urllib3
pip install pyopenssl
pip install ndg-httpsclient
pip install pyasn1
```

solution from:

> https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/issues/267

Answer (score 1):

This is not a django issue, but operating system and language issue.

I'm using Mac OS X and and a brew version of python.  I'm also using virtual env which has its own copy of python and open ssl.

I did the following:

I first downloaded the most recent version of XCode which updates OpenSSL.
I then uninstalled and reinstalled brew python.
I then updated virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried to update openssl and python (using brew), and still does not work, make sure your settings have DEBUG = False.

Watch this thread for more information https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13207