# Enable TLS 1.2 on Mac OSX

Tags: django, macos, ssl, tls1.2

I am pulling my hair out trying to get a Django application working with Stripe on my local machine with OSX 10.12.3. The error I get when trying to run a test payment is:

> PermissionError at /register Request req_ADIwntj3xGaqUF: Stripe no
>   longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS
>   connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at
>   https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.

I successfully upgraded openssl using brew. When I run `openssl version` the output is:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

When I run `which openssl` the output is:

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

I found instructions on stack overflow that said to run `brew link --force openssl`. When I do that the error is:

> Warning: Refusing to link: openssl Linking keg-only openssl means you
>   may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL
>   while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl. Instead, pass the
>   full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
>   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Can anybody help me get this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem’s in the Python environment and the solution to try seems to be the following:

```
pip install urllib3
pip install pyopenssl
pip install ndg-httpsclient
pip install pyasn1
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
```

See https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/issues/267 and [How to run django runserver over TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279079/how-to-run-django-runserver-over-tls-1-2)

That’s all assuming you’re running Python 2.7.9+. Earlier Python versions have no TLS 1.2 support.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using `brew` + `pyenv` + `pyenv-virtualenv` this is what fixed my issue with missing TLS 1.2 on my Mac:

```
# Update XCode 
# Restart machine
Type:
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade pyenv
$ pyenv install 3.4.6 # the latest version of Python 3.4
$ pyenv global 3.4.6  # make default python
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.4.6 myenv
$ pyenv activate myenv
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Hope that's useful to someone someday.