# Unable to get TLS1.2 working on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, ssl, stripe-connect

1) I'm running Google App Engine SDK on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have Python 2.7.13

2) While trying to test my app with Stripe, I get the following error

Request req_ApPsfecKnLFJxb: Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.

3) I did some Googling and based on what I found, I did the following

a) Used brew to upgrade my OpenSSL

b) Confirmed that when I do 'which openssl', I get

/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

and when I do 'openssl version', I get

OpenSSL 1.0.2l

c) If I do

import ssl

ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION, I get

'OpenSSL 1.0.2l  23 May 2017'

But I still get the error from Stripe about not using TLS 1.2.

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566809/enable-tls-1-2-on-mac-osx) but it didn't solve my problem. I also found this[Google Group Discussion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900856) and after running the steps in #5, it shows app engine is still pointing to the old version of OPENSSL because the output shows 'OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016'

How do I fix this? How do I get python or app engine to use the newer version of OpenSSL that I've installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and my understanding is

1) GAE was still referring to the old python installation (the one that comes shipped with Mac). When I open the GAE Launcher, 
GAE > Preferences > Python Path is blank.

2) What I needed to do was force GAE to use the newly installed Python (the one I installed with Brew with the direction to use the upgraded OpenSSL). So I have now set
GAE > Preferences > Python Path = /usr/local/bin/python.

Everything now works and running the code below from within GAE tells me my TLS is OKAY

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen("https://howsmyssl.com/").read()
return r
```

Also running the code below now gives me the updated version of OpenSSL

```
import ssl 
return ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you upgrade to latest version of the App Engine SDK.  Also, add this to your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: '2.7.11'
```

Comment: My app.yaml already includes ssl but the version is 'latest'. I previously tried 2.7.11 but it didn't fix the issue. I'll try upgrading to the latest SDK version

Comment: upgrading to the latest version of App Engine SDK did not fix the issue